# Can you put a tabindex on a <a> element in HTML and when it is tabbed to it is clicked instead of having to be entered on?

Tags: javascript, html, tabindex

I have a bunch of `<input>`s that I have in a certain tab sequence. The last tab is a `<a>` that when clicked on adds another `<input>` to the list. Is there a way to use javascript or just plain HTML to make it so that when the user tabs to that link it executes the link?

Comment: Doesn't the `a` element receive focus when you tab to it? If so you can just execute some javascript in `onfocus`.

Comment: @Klaus, didn't think about that option. I will try that out. thanks.

Comment: @Klaus You should have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: If the A only adds the INPUT on CLICK, it should only add the INPUT on ENTER. If you want it to add the INPUT on TAB, it should also add the INPUT on hover. Else your mouse-keyboard navigation shows different behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't the `a` element receive focus when you tab to it? If so you can just execute some javascript in `onfocus`

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

You can use the anchor onfocus event. See:

```
<a href="#123" onfocus="Test(this);">Test</a>
```

And the function "Test" must read the "href" attribute, something like:

```
        function Test(target)
        {
            location.href = target.getAttribute('href');
        }
```